# Efficiency of "begins with substring" techniques in Delphi?

Tags: performance, delphi

How does the performance of these two ways of determining whether a string begins with a certain substring in Delphi compare? Is one significantly faster/more efficient than the other?

```
  if ((testString[1] = '=') AND (testString[2] = '?')) then ...
```

vs.

```
  if (AnsiStartsStr('=?', testString)) then ...
```

Comment: Evaluating from left to right is not required for the first method. You can adjust it to filter out the least frequent occurrences first. For example, you could test for the question mark first if it were less frequent.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, the first will definitely be faster.  Solving a hard-coded, highly specific problem almost always goes a lot faster than passing a specific solution to a general-problem-solving routine.  As for "significantly" faster, why don't you test it?  Run both versions it in a loop 10 million times and use `TStopwatch` (or something else if you don't have D2010 or later) to time it.

One other thing: The first is definitely faster, but it might also be wrong.  If `length(TestString)` is not guaranteed to be >= 2, you could have an error condition here.  If `TestString` is an empty string, this will raise an exception.  If not, you may or may not get an exception depending on compiler settings.

Comment: Good point. The first is not always safe. It at least needs `if Length(testString)>=2) and ...`

Comment: The short circuit evaluation of the AND is a big help too, in cases where it doesn't match.

Comment: @MarcusAdams If you neglected the LOCALE aspect of `AnsiStartsStr`, then `AnsiStartsStr` could be implemented just as efficiently as the explicit `if` (although it almost certainly isn't)

Comment: @David, I think you're right, but `AnsiStartStr` uses native `CompareString`, so it's hard to say.

Comment: @marcus yeah ok but you could write an inlined function that was efficient

Comment: @David, definitely. Other functions like `CompareMem` will return early, without evaluating the whole thing.

Answer (score 4):

If you need speed with flexibility you can try something like:

```
function StatsWith(const SubStr, Str: string): Boolean; inline;
begin
  if Length(SubStr) <= Length(Str) then
    Result := CompareMem(Pointer(SubStr), Pointer(Str), ByteLength(SubStr))
  else
    Result := False;
end;
```

Comment: ByteLength() will work with Delphi 2009+ only I suspect.   `length(SubStr)*sizeof(char)` is more standard.

Comment: @ArnaudBouchez If you have no intention of supporting old compiler versions, then `ByteLength` is clearer.

Comment: ByteLength is implemented (in D2010) as an inline function that is implemented as `Length(s) * SizeOf(Char)`...  Anyway, that might be overkill, but I'd probably go with `Length(s) * StringElementSize(s)`.

Answer (score 2):

The first in CPU window is just `mov`, `cmp` and `jnz` (eventually repeated one time) while the second looks far more complicated (uses `Copy` and WinApi's `CompareString`). First should be faster.

Comment: `AnsiStartsStr()` using `Copy()` internally is a bad implementation on Borland's part, IMHO.  They could have used `CompareString()` without `Copy()` like `AnsiStartsText()` does, just call `CompareString()` with different flags.  Too bad CodeGear and Embarcadero never fixed that over the years after Borland gave up ownership of its developer tools.

Comment: @RemyLebeau-TeamB Main bottleneck of `AnsiStartsStr` is not the internal `copy` use, but use of `AnsiSameStr` which calls the very slow `CompareString` Windows API. In fact, most `Ansi*` functions are calling those APIs and are slow if the whole Unicode handling is not necessary (e.g. when using Ascii 7 bit characters, which happens a lot in programming). The whole RTL is full of working code, but not written for speed. My favorite is `IntToStr` implementation which is just damn slow (even slower since Delphi 2009).